# How to access multiple buttons or textbox or any control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I want to access multiple `textbox` name *textbox1,textbox2,textbox3, etc..* by loop not by individual name. For that reason I created one function which create this var names.

```
public string[] nameCre(string cntrlName, int size)
{
    string[] t = new string[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        t[i] = cntrlName.ToString() + (i + 1);
    }
    return t;
}
```

for `nameCre("Textbox",5);` So this,function successfully returning me TextBox1, TextBox2 ... TextBox5.

But when I am trying to convert this string to TextBox control by

```
string[] t = new string[50];
t=  nameCre("TextBox",5);    
foreach (string s in t)
{
    ((TextBox) s).Text = "";
}
```

it giving me error :

> Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'....

How can I accomplish this job?

Comment: No you cannot! You cannot convert "string" to a "TextBox"... What exactly are you trying to do here??

Comment: Do you already have textboxes "TextBox1", "TextBox2" etc.. and you are trying to fetch them and set their Text to ""?

Comment: @PrateekSingh yes, thats what i want to do

Comment: In that case, @GTSouza has already answered correctly...

Comment: I am using Visual C#, not asp.net. I couldn't get 'FindControl' function, I am getting only Find().

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] t= new string[50];
    t= nameCre("TextBox",5);

foreach (string s in t){
TextBox tb = (TextBox)this.Controls.FindControl(s);
tb.Text = "";
}
```

if you have many text boxes

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
  if (c.GetType().ToString() == "System.Windows.Form.Textbox")
  {
    c.Text = "";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = nameCre("TextBox",5);

foreach (var s in t)
{
    var textBox = new TextBox {Name = s, Text = ""};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need this -

```
        string[] t = new string[50];
        t = nameCre("TextBox", 5);

        foreach (string s in t)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            {
                Control ctrl = this.Controls.Find(s, true).FirstOrDefault();
                if (ctrl != null && ctrl is TextBox)
                {
                    TextBox tb = ctrl as TextBox;
                    tb.Text = "";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried this code. I am getting lots of error :  
1) I can't use var.  "The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"   

2)'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' 

3)Cannot convert type 'var' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' via a built-in conversion.

Comment: What .Net version you are using?

Comment: I have updated the code above to take care of your exceptions num 1 & 3. For 2, add reference for System.Linq - `using System.Linq` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This post is quite old, anyway I think I can give you (or anyone else with a problem like that) an answer:

I think using an Array (or List) of TextBoxs would be the best solution for doing that:

```
        // using an Array:
        TextBox[] textBox = new TextBox[5];
        textBox[0] = new TextBox() { Location = new Point(), /* etc */};
        // or
        textBox[0] = TextBox0; // if you already have a TextBox named TextBox0

        // loop it:
        for (int i = 0; i < textBox.Length; i++)
        {
            textBox[i].Text = "";
        }

        // using a List:  (you need to reference System.Collections.Generic)
        List<TextBox> textBox = new List<TextBox>();
        textBox.Add(new TextBox() { Name = "", /* etc */});
        // or
        textBox.Add(TextBox0); // if you already have a TextBox named TextBox0

        // loop it:
        for (int i = 0; i < textBox.Count; i++)
        {
            textBox[i].Text = "";
        }
```

I hope this helps :)